# My AMD RX580 GPU suddenly stopped outputting display, started working 5 days later, and has stopped again. Is this an issue with my video drivers?

Tags: gpu, display-driver

About a week ago, my PC stopped outputting any display, though it booted up fine (as the motherboard lit up and all the fans started).

After changing the monitor and HDMI cable to ascertain that they were working fine, I tried a bunch of recommended solutions from websites, such as reseating the RAM sticks, reseating the GPU, and even resetting the BIOS by taking out the motherboard's button battery and putting it back in. Nothing worked.

About 5 days later I tried again and the display suddenly started working. I opened my AMD software: Adrenalin edition because I suspected something was wrong with the drivers, but it gave the alert:

"The version of AMD Software: Adrenalin Edition you have launched is not compatible with your currently installed graphics driver."

So I tried to uninstall and reinstall the software, and the moment I download the disk image of the new AMD software my screen goes blank again.

I am sure that the issue can't be with the hardware of the GPU since it was brand new and I've only used it for 2 years. Does anyone have any ideas as to what the issue could be, and how I would go about fixing it.

Comment: "was brand new" and "only used it for 2 years" are contradictory. It sounds like your GPU may have failed.

Comment: I would check if the graphic card is still correctly mounted in it's PCI express card slot. May be the card got loose and is now sometimes correctly connected to the mainboard and sometimes not.

Comment: @Mokubai I meant that I'd bought it brand new and not second hand, and that I've been using it for 2 years, so I wouldn't expect the GPU itself to fail.

Comment: Electronics fail all the time. 2 years is not great by any means, but at that age I would never rule out failure.